# Autocompletion in a TextBox - VBA

Tags: excel, vba, text, autocomplete, text-extraction

I am trying to do a function to do some autocompletion in a TextBox. I want to autocomplete word per word but currently the autocompletion is only effective on the first typed word.
For exemple if i write "ba" it autocompletes easely with "banana" from the column wanted no problem on this point. But when I write another word after "banana" (with one space between them two obviously) the autocomplete is not working. It only work on one word

Can you help me ? Here is new code :

```
Private Sub TextBoxComm_Change()
Dim lastRow As Long
Dim searchRange As Range
Dim foundCell As Range
Dim chaine, Mot_Proposé As String
Dim word As String 'WORD FAIT OFFICE DE SEArch string

 If m_ignore Then Exit Sub

'Définition du champs de recherche
word = TextBoxComm.text
Set searchRange = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Base de données").ListObjects("RCA").ListColumns("Numéro de commande").DataBodyRange

'si c'est vide ne rien faire
If word = "" Then Exit Sub

'Trouve la dernière cellule de la colonne
lastRow = searchRange.Find(What:="*", SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row

' Si le mot tapé n'apparaît trouver le mot le plus ressemblant
Set foundCell = searchRange.Find(What:=word & "*", LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole)

If Not foundCell Is Nothing Then
        'Compléter le mot tapé
        chaine = foundCell.Value
        m_currentSuggestion = Find_Mot(word, chaine)
        TextBoxComm.text = m_currentSuggestion
        
    If Len(m_currentSuggestion) > 0 Then
        m_currentText = m_currentSuggestion
        m_selectionStart = Len(word)
        m_selectionLength = Len(m_currentSuggestion) - Len(word)
        
        TextBoxComm.text = m_currentText
        TextBoxComm.SelStart = m_selectionStart
        TextBoxComm.SelLength = m_selectionLength
        
    End If
    End If
    
   End Sub
```

And my first version was this one : (just on another TextBox but i apply the same code on every textbox)

```
'Machine
Private Sub TextBoxMach_Change()
Dim lastRow As Long
Dim searchRange As Range
Dim searchString As String
Dim foundCell As Range
Dim chaine, Mot_Proposé As String

 If m_ignore Then Exit Sub

'Définition du champs de recherche
Set searchRange = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Base de données").ListObjects("RCA").ListColumns("Type de machine").DataBodyRange
searchString = TextBoxMach.text

'Ne rien faire si le TextBox est vide
If searchString = "" Then Exit Sub

'Trouve la dernière cellule de la colonne
lastRow = searchRange.Find(What:="*", SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row

'Chercher si le mot tapé apparaît déjà dans la colonne
Set foundCell = searchRange.Find(What:=searchString, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole)


If Not foundCell Is Nothing Then
    'Si oui, autocomplétion
        
    chaine = foundCell.Value
    Mot_Proposé = Find_Mot(searchString, chaine)
    TextBoxMach.text = Mot_Proposé
    
    TextBoxMach.SelStart = Len(searchString)
    TextBoxMach.SelLength = Len(foundCell.Value) - Len(searchString)
Else
    ' Si le mot tapé n'apparaît trouver le mot le plus ressemblant
    Set foundCell = searchRange.Find(What:=searchString & "*", LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole)


If Not foundCell Is Nothing Then
        'Compléter le mot tapé
        
        chaine = foundCell.Value
        Mot_Proposé = Find_Mot(searchString, chaine)
        TextBoxMach.text = Mot_Proposé
    
        TextBoxMach.SelStart = Len(searchString)
        TextBoxMach.SelLength = Len(foundCell.Value) - Len(searchString)
End If
End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

I was looking for something similar myself today for WPF and bumped into a post on learn.microsoft.com. I translated it from C# to VBA and fixed an issue with the Backspace key that was preventing a letter to be deleted when the key was pressed.

The example uses a hard-coded list of words, but you can modify it to get the data from Excel to fill an array when the form is initialized.

Source: [Auto Complete for TextBox in WPF (MVVM)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/840981/auto-complete-for-textbox-in-wpf-(mvvm))

---

Private fields and source collection:

```
Option Explicit

Private m_words As VBA.Collection
Private m_currentInput As String
Private m_currentSuggestion As String
Private m_currentText As String
Private m_selectionStart As Integer
Private m_selectionLength As Integer
Private m_ignore As Boolean

'Initialize source
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    Set m_words = New VBA.Collection
    Populate
End Sub

Private Sub Populate()
    m_words.Add "English"
    m_words.Add "Chinese"
    m_words.Add "French"
    m_words.Add "French one"
    m_words.Add "French two"
    m_words.Add "Russian"
    m_words.Add "Japanese"
End Sub
```

---

The `Change()` event handler:

```
'Change()
Private Sub AutoTextBox_Change()

    If m_ignore Then Exit Sub
    
    Dim word As String
        word = AutoTextBox.Text
    
    If Len(word) > Len(m_currentInput) And word <> m_currentSuggestion Then
        
        m_currentSuggestion = FindWord(word)
        
        If Len(m_currentSuggestion) > 0 Then
            m_currentText = m_currentSuggestion
            m_selectionStart = Len(word)
            m_selectionLength = Len(m_currentSuggestion) - Len(word)
            
            AutoTextBox.Text = m_currentText
            AutoTextBox.SelStart = m_selectionStart
            AutoTextBox.SelLength = m_selectionLength
        End If
    End If
    
End Sub
```

---

A helper method to search for the keyed word, similar to the C# `StartsWith(string)`.

```
'Find word in source that starts with given param.
Private Function FindWord(ByVal beginsWith As String) As String
    
    Dim i As Integer
    
    For i = 1 To m_words.Count
        If LCase(Left(m_words(i), Len(beginsWith))) = LCase(beginsWith) Then
            FindWord = m_words(i)
            Exit Function
        End If
    Next
    
    FindWord = vbNullString
    
End Function
```

Using an array, the loop  is slightly different:

```
For i = LBound(array) To UBound(array)
    '...
Next
```

---

A hack to suspend the `TextBox_Change()` event when the Backspace key is pressed:

```
'Suspend the Change() event to allow the backspace key.
Private Sub AutoTextBox_KeyDown(ByVal KeyCode As MSForms.ReturnInteger, ByVal Shift As Integer)
    m_ignore = Len(AutoTextBox.Text) > 0 And KeyCode = 8 'Backspace key
End Sub
```

---

Result:

[image: Autocomplete]

Comment: Hey, first a huge thanks for your help. I successfuly implemented your ocde in mine but I still have the same problem of the autocompletion on only the first word typed

Comment: Hi, I cant really tell what's wrong. As you can see above, the *French one* and *French two* examples are working fine. Edit your post and insert the new code below the original (don't change the original) noting that you incorporated the answer to your solution but still fails.

Comment: You can now find the first and new version